# Route Table Details

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Is there a way to fetch all details of routing from each subscription with Route-Table Name, subscriptions, next hop type address prefix.

I have tried 'Get-AzRouteTable  -ResourceGroupName "*" -Name "prod*" | Get-AzRouteConfig | Export-Csv azureroutetable2.csv' but getting only from specific environment, is there a better way to do the same?

Regards

Devbrat

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the help for `Get-AzRouteTable` it doesn't require any value to be specified for `ResourceGroupName` so we should just be able to loop through your available contexts. If you did have a large Azure Network infrastructure and they were logically organised by Resource Group, you may want to consider looping through Resource Groups too.

That being said, you can do something like this. It will create a csv for each subscription in your current session. Change the `.` at the beginning of the path value to set a full path if you would like.

```
$Contexts = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
foreach ($Context in $Contexts) {
    [void](Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Context.Subscription.Id)
    $RouteConfig = Get-AzRouteTable -Name "prod" | Get-AzRouteConfig
    # If you are using PowerShell 5.1, add '-NoTypeInformation' to the end of this command.
    $RouteConfig | Export-Csv -Path ".\$($Context.Subscription.Name)_Routes.csv" -Encoding utf8 -NoClobber
}
```